# XCode 4.1 - Multiple view within a XIB

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I have created an application successfully and given it a TabBar view controller that is working as i had hoped, but have run into a glitch.

On each xib i load from the tabBar I need to create sub-views that will perform tasks as this interacts with a database (or .. will). I have created my first page and the buttons that will navigate to the views within the XIB, but do not yet nkow how to navigate between views within the XIB itself.

1. would it be better to have seperate XIB's that load when the buttons are hit?
   OR
2. should i create views within the XIB's for each category and switch between them?

I am still learning and have had some confusion regarding navigation as I already have the TabBar controlling the root of the application.  I have been looking for tutorials, but they all seem to start at either navigation controller as the root, TabBar as the root, and nothing like I need for option 1 above.

I can add details of the app if needed, but am looking for guidance for now.

Thank you,

Silver Tiger

Comment: it is better to have multiple XIBs, as you may not want to mix up different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate between views the best way is to use a navigation controller pushing/popping separate view controllers, loaded from separate nibs. UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController, so you can perfectly put a navigation controller for each tab. You can also use story-boarding in the new xcode 4.2, but I recommend getting comfortable with this before doing so.

Comment: heh.. all new to me so I'll have to read a lot.  I started with online tutorials to set up a window based app and get my 5 main views using a tabBar .. is it possible to have UINavigationController within each if my 5 category XIB's (already working under the tabBar) so ican switch between views on them or should i scrap the tabbar and start over with NavigatioController?

Comment: Yes you can have a UINavigationController for each tab (in the MainWindow.xib, under the tab bar controller, you should have view controllers, replace them by navigation controllers, add set the root controller of each navigation controller to be the view controller you want).

Comment: well .. upgrading to 4.2 i can only do the Storyoard if i want to limit my platform to ios 5.0 or higher :(... but creating projects changed up a bit so there is a Tabed Application" that gives me a good start .. but now there is no mainwindow.xib .. starting over and reading more is the plan of the day...

Comment: How would i do this programattically? When i create a tabbed application in XCode 4.2, and specify anything other than ios5 i get no mainwindow.xib file .....

Comment: to note, most of the controls i used were replaced with the default TabBar, and subsequent imbedded navigation views.  the only issue i have pending is how to navigate from a view "under" one specific tab in the tabBar, directly to a view "under" another tabBar item directly .. without having it be a push or modal "change" ..